# Trackpad and keyboard does not resume after sleep

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, suspend

On my laptop Toshiba Satellite L50-A-1D6/VG10S it seems pretty frequently keybord or/and trackpad do not resume after sleep. I found many questions pretty similar but no solution for me. Anyone who solved similar issues? This is the log of dmesg right after a resume in which both keyboard and trackpad failed to resume: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13144230/. I had to plug in a USB keyboard to get the log. Any idea on how to fix or on how to investigate further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something changed in the kernel and updates fixed the issue many months ago.